# Why classes implicitly derive from only the Object Class?

Tags: object, language-agnostic, programming-languages

I do not have any argument opposing why we need only a single universal class. However why not we have two universal classes, say an Object and an AntiObject Class. 
In nature and in science we find the concept of duality - like Energy & Dark Energy; Male & Female; Plus & Minus; Multiply & Divide; Electrons & Protons; Integration & Derivation; and in set theory. There are so many examples of dualism that it is a philosophy in itself. In programming itself we see Anti-Patterns which helps us to perform work in contrast to how we use Design patterns. 
We call it object-oriented programming. Is that a limiting factor or is there something fundamental I am missing in understanding the formation of programming languages?

Edit: 
I am not sure, but the usefulness of this duality concept may lie in creating garbage collectors that create AntiObjects that combine with free or loose Objects to destruct themselves, thereby releasing memory. Or may be AntiObjects work along with Objects to create a self-modifying programming language - that allows us to create a safe self modifying code, do evolutionary computing using genetic programming, do hiding of code to prevent reverse engineering.
I've moved this question to Computer Science Site of Stack Exchange, as this is considered off-topic here. Please use that if you want to comment/answer this question.

Comment: I'm fine with that. Just provide a single superclass for these two classes so we can cram them in universal containers. Oh... wait. Seriously though, this is a very interesting but really philosophical question. Sadly, I doubt it suits this site.

Comment: The central idea of oo,everything is object.

Comment: What purpose would your anti-object serve?  Without your concept having a *meaning* to it, nobody would create it.

Comment: Someday, I'm going to ask it as an interview question.

Comment: The language [Ithkuil](http://www.ithkuil.net/index.htm) is completely based on the idea of single category which are modified by regular suffixes/prefixes/infixes to specialize "Living Being" into "male" and "female." Duality in nature may just be subjective.

Comment: @Xantix +1, but attaching suffixes/ prefixes to male and female is like making males wear women's clothes and vice versa. it doesn't change the inherent nature of them being stark opposites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inheritance tree is commonly (as it is in C#) a tree, with a single root, for a number of reasons, which all seem to lead back to one big one:

- If there were multiple roots, there wouldn't be a way to specify "any type of object" (aside from something like C++'s `void *`, which would be hideous as it tosses away any notion of "type").
- Even the *idea* of "any type of object" loses some usefulness, as you can no longer guarantee *anything* about the objects you'll be accepting.  How do you say "all objects have properties *a, b,* and *c*" in such a way as to let programs actually use them?  You'd need an interface that all of them implement...and then, *that interface becomes the root type*.
- GC'able languages would be useless if they couldn't collect every type of object they manage.  *Oops*, there goes that "any type of object" again!

All-around, it's simpler to have one type be the root of the hierarchy.  It lets you make contracts/guarantees/etc that apply to every object in the system, and makes fewer demands on code that wants to be able to deal with objects in a universal manner.

C++ gets away with having multiple root types because (1) C++ allows multiple inheritance, so objects can bridge the gaps between inheritance trees; (2) it has templates (which are far, *far* more able than generics to take any type of object); (3) it can discard and sidestep any notion of "type" altogether via means like `void *`; and (4) it doesn't offer to manage and collect your objects for you.

C# didn't want all the complexity of multiple inheritance and templates, and it wanted garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks for assessing it in a methodical manner. You did mention a very useful role of GC in the design of "Object Orientation". May be when we have AntiObjects, we do not need GC to work in the way it works now. In the dual system an AntiObject looks for a free Object and they both dissapper, satisfying the need to collect free and unused Objects.

Answer (score 2):

In Nature, if in a family there are two children who are totally different and opposite from each other, still they have common parents.

All those examples which you have given come under common category. For e.g. Male and Female comes under Homosapiens Category. Plus and Minus come under Operator category.

In OOPS also there are two types. Reference type and value type but still they both come under object.

What you are suggesting is also good. But let us for a second, in a universe, accept what you are suggesting. Still there will be a `Super_Class` containing your Object and AntiObject class. So it has to stop somewhere and in OOPS `object` is that class where it stops.

Comment: Only two parents could make children.

Comment: No, no, no. Male and female is completely separate from *Homo sapiens*. Composition would be a better way to solve this problem. I love how this is turning into a chicken-and-egg dilemma.

Comment: @user854301 tell that to the amoeba, many species of plant, a good number of lizards, ...

Comment: @MarcGravell: Love u for your comment.

Comment: @MarcGravell those simple organisms works like a `.Clone()` their result *practically* identical with their parents. (holy war raises)